# Rendering a text and coloring it using Freetype/Harfbuzz

Tags: freetype2, harfbuzz

I have rendered a text in Freetype and have converted it to a bitmap using Freetype.The created bitmap is stored in a character array which is later processed by Targa Reader into a .tga image.NOW,How and when do I assign colour to the glyph while I am converting the glyph to a bitmap or should I use Freetype or Harfbuzz to colour it?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think harfbuzz does something like this for you, it is just a shaping library.
But with freetype, as far as I know, there are two approaches to paint the glyphs and draw them to a bitmap. 
first. by default, I guess, it renders a glyph to a grayscale bitmap.
second. you can take control of rendering the glyphs by sending some callbacks to the freetype engine and instead of freetype doing that, it calls those functions, one of which is for drawing the scanline spans with alpha, coverage, x and y parameters for you to easily manipulate the bitmap.

you can find more about what I am talking about in one of the freetype's c example source code @freetpye.org

And if you find it too complicated which i don't think it is, If your rendered bitmap is all gray and you want to apply your own color to it, as Ebrahim suggests, you can use the bitmap's pixel values as alpha and do something like this:

```
unsigned char alpha = src[x, y];
red = color.r * alpha / 0xff;
green = color.g * alpha / 0xff;
blue = color.b * alpha / 0xff;
dst[x, y] = Color(red, green, blue);
```

hope they could be any of help.

Answer (score 1):

harfbuzz is not very related here as it doesn't care about rendering aspects itself.

But freetype, as it usual way of use (considering not talking about color emojis or other edge cases I am not familiar with), FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL render mode, gives you a grayscale bitmap which every pixel allocates one char, unlike a color image which needs 3 times more size (or 4 if you have alpha channel also), and it doesn't care about color AFAIK so all you need to do so is to multiply the grayscale output of freetype rendering to the color you want. Something like this pseudocode:

```
coloredImage[x, y].r = r * grayScale[x, y] / 255;
coloredImage[x, y].g = g * grayScale[x, y] / 255;
coloredImage[x, y].b = b * grayScale[x, y] / 255;
```